# How to push changes to a Git repository from a website

Tags: javascript, git

In our company, we are managing translations in a Git repo. However, business people (no IT knowledge) have to be able to update the translations as well. Hence, I wanted to create a web application to update them. When changes are done, I want a 'Save' button on the web app, that pushes the changes to Git.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: I would research "Web Hooks" you can use these to check for changes and then do a git pull/push to track your changes.

Comment: I believe git provides guides about this.

Comment: maybe you can use GitHub.js https://medium.freecodecamp.org/pushing-a-list-of-files-to-the-github-with-javascript-b724c8c09b66

Answer (score 0):

not directly an answer to your question but I found that some SaaS has sufficient online editing with great git integration.
notable examples: [github](http://github.com) and [cloud9](https://c9.io/).

you can edit the files online and submit the changes to git.
of course it might not fit your needs but it's an interesting concept.
especially when you think of the complexity of implementing version control, users authorization and conflict solving to a web editor

Comment: Indeed the online edit can be really useful. We use Gitlab and it offers it as well. But the problem is that it's a JSON file, which already looks like "code" to some business people.